# Paralelism with Gunicorn, Ngnix and Celery

Tags: nginx, process, parallel-processing, celery, gunicorn

i am not sure how paralelism can be or should be combined between gunicorn and celery (and probably ngnix).

1) So first of all I use Nginx.

2) Secondly, i run gunicorn like this ***gunicorn -k gevent --worker-connections 1001 --bind=unix:myapp.sock -m 007 wsgi:application***

3) Thirdly i run celery like this - ***celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=4***

With this configuration i suspect I get one process of my app from gunicorn with 1001 workers (threads ?) that can serve each request independently. Correct? Then from celerey i should get additional paralelism for each gunicorn thread or process? Like, do i even need celery at this point? Can i just make 100 processes that could independently serve different requests?